# Laravel 5.6. Form validation in the custom package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-localization

I'm making custom package and have problems with localized  validation attribute output. How can I fix this problem? It returns `post_localizations.en.post_title` instead of localized string `Post title (EN)`

I have input in my form:
`<input type="text" name="post_localizations[ru][post_title]" />`

And validations in my Controller is:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'post_localizations.*.post_title' => 'required|max:70'
        ], trans('namespace::validation'));
```

`validation.php` in my package:

```
'attributes' => [
        'post_localizations.*.post_title' => 'Post title (EN)'
]
```

Loading translations in in `boot` method of the Provider:

`$this->loadTranslationsFrom(
            __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'resources' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lang', 'namespace');`

All are works fine if I'm inserting my attribute to default laravel
`resource/lang/en/validation.php`. 
Also all are fine if string of input name simple like `post_title`:

`<input type="text" name="post_title" />`

`'attributes' => [
            'post_title' => 'Post title'
    ]`

Comment: this is just a list of statements ... there is nothing to answer here, no question

Comment: @lagbox "I'm making custom package and have problems with localized validation attribute output."